# Turning regular foreach into parallel.foreach or parallel.for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, foreach, parallel-processing

I'm trying to turn this piece of code into a parallel loop like:

```
foreach (var item in filteredList)
{
    var itm = ctx.SearchedUserItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemID == item.ItemID);
    if (itm == null)
    {
        ss.Add(new SearchedUserItems() { ItemID = item.ItemID, QuantitySold = item.QuantitySold, SearchedUserID = updatedUser.SearchedUserID });
    }
    else if (item != null)
    {
        if (itm.QuantitySold != item.QuantitySold)
        {
            newFilteredList.Add(item);
            itm.QuantitySold = item.QuantitySold;
            ctx.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

By using Parallel.For or Parallel.Foreach loop to speed things up..

The thing is I always get object reference not set to an instance at this line of code:

```
var itm = ctx.SearchedUserItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemID == item.ItemID);
```

I create the ctx object of my model outside of this for loop like this:

```
var ctx = new myDBModel();
```

I realize I need to create a new instance of my db model each time a new thread is created like this:

```
using(var ctx = new myDBModel())
{
// do some parallel stuff here...
}
```

The problem here is that ss collection is a concurrent bag while the newFilteredList is just a plain simple list...

If I used a Parallel.For loop here I'd have problems because list isn't thread safe...

I'm thinking to use PLINQ for this but then I don't know how should I optimize my code so that I can avoid any possible error when turning this into a multi-threaded piece of code....

So the ss collection is typed of ConcurrengBag and newFilteredList is plain regular List...

How can I turn this piece of code so that it performs these operations concurrently?

Comment: What part of this do you expect to be sped up with using parallel? None of this is CPU intensive. Since it looks like you're using EntityFramework, why not just mark your method as async and call savechangesasync? that's the only part that might really slow it down.

Comment: You can't fix bad query performance by executing *more* inefficient queries in parallel. *Instead* of perfoming multiple queries, modify your code to essentially execute an `ItemID in ...) ` query, eg `ctx.SearchedUserItems.Where(x=>filteredList.Contains(x.ItemId))`. That translates to `WHERE ItemID in (1,5,6,7...)`

Comment: @Dispersia The only outcome that I want from this is that I speed up the execution time of this code... Right now as it is ,  if the collection filteredList contains 5-10000 items , which it does on many occasions, it's very very slow for the CPU, that's why  I need to reduce the execution time...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Are there any other ways to speed it up... Like for example if filteredList has 10000 items, it takes like 10-15 minutes for this code to finish , and it's performance is utterly terrible :/

Comment: Also make sure `ItemId` is indexed. Furthermore, what `FilteredList` contain? Where does it come from? If it comes from the database, you should have proper relations defined between its entities and `SearchedUserItems` so that you can load all related objects simply by loading the root  items

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos The FilteredList  is not coming from DB, but is a rather list of  custom type of class that I've created ... The data of it exists only in runtime until it's saved into DB

Comment: @User987 it's impossible to help because you didn't explain what the classes are or where they come from. We can only offer generic advice. 10K is essentially no data. Whatever the code does, it's completely wrong. Loading each item individually with `FirstOrDefault` is *definitely* wrong - it's 10000 times slower than a single query that loads all 10K items at once. Doing *anything* in memory when you have a database is also a bad idea. The database has indexes. Client code can only loop

Comment: What is this code trying to do? An UPSERT? That's **not** what ORMs are about. It's like trying to work with tweezers when you need a bulldozer. Just load the data into a temporary/staging table, join with the target table and perform either a MERGE or a plain old UPDATE followed by an INSERT. One bulk operation that should take 1-2 seconds, followed by only 2 queries.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will update my question with the info you guys need.. Btw. the .ctx.SearchedUserItems doesn't contains 10k records, but rather around 5-6 millions of records. It might be a bad idea to load it all in memory with .tolist()?

Comment: @User987 doing anything other that BULK INSERT and UPSERT on the database is a bad idea. Trying to do that with a DataMart's worth of data is impossible. You are using a completely inappropriate tool. ORMs at tweezers for working with individual pebbles/objects. You have a truckload of them. You can't use tweezers

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos what would you recommend me to do ?

Comment: @User987 I already did, twice. Load the data into a temporary table using either your database's BULK INSERT functionality or .NET's SqlBulkCopy, then user an UPDATE to update all matching records, followed by an INSERT to insert all new ones. If you work with SQL Server, use SSIS. Find books and courses on data warehousing and ETL. That kind of work is completely different from web applications and ORMs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos SaveChanges will handle all of this for you. He should just have every item prepared, and THEN call AddRange (so changes are only detected once instead of n amount), then save changes just once. You don't need to manually do anything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you give me some links which might help me? I'm a bit confused on the part how to create a temp table using linq ... ?

Comment: @Dispersia could you post an answer so that I can see what you mean ?

Comment: @Dispersia SaveChanges will execute 10K individual operations for no reason at all. 10K individual network operations. Even if you try to use batching (only available as an extension) you get 10K individual inserts when you could insert everything at once with minimal logging. ORMs are completely inappropriate for this. In fact, it's *ORMs* that require manual work - manual checking, manual insertion, manual updates

Comment: @User987 f.o.r.g.e.t LINQ. That's just database development. The easiest way to do this is with SQL. SSIS makes this faster - in fact, SQL Server's import wizard will generate the temporary table for you.